# How can we consume the SAML token in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: claims-based-auth, windows-authentication, token, saml

Can anybody tell me , how can we consume a SAML token in SharePoint 2013 and identify whether the user with SAML token is valid or not . Also how  can we send the appropriate response to SAML again ?

Is there any c# code for the same which will work for SharePoint 2013 ?